# How do programmatically create fields for content types, and ADD them to the the content type form

Tags: 7, nodes

Say I have this field, "map_description". I know I would this function to define the field:

```
$field = array(
  'field_name' => 'map_description',
  'cardinality' => 1,
  'type' => 'text',
);
field_create_field($field);
```

And I have this code which I'm not sure what it does but I'm told that I'll need it:

```
 $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'map_description',
    'label' => 'The map description.',
    'bundle' => 'my_content_type',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'widget' => array(
    'type' => 'text_textfield',
 );
 field_create_instance($instance)
```

Those two code bits are both in my install hook and run when I install the module. But while the fields are in fact created, I have to manually assign them to the content type via "manage fields", is there a way to have the fields automatically assigned to the content type?

Answer (score 10):

You're almost there.

From your code:

```
'bundle' => 'my_content_type',
```

Replace *my_content_type* with the name of the content type you want it attached to.

Here's a full example of adding a *Alias* text field to the *Article* content type. (from [monarchdigital.com](http://www.monarchdigital.com/blog/2013-08-14/drupal-7-field-api))

```
/**
 * Update hook to add a field to a node.
 */
function my_module_update_7000() {
  $field_name = 'field_alias';
  // Make sure the field doesn't already exist.
  if (!field_info_field($field_name)) {
    // Create the field.
    $field = array(
      'field_name' => $field_name,
      'type' => 'text',
      'settings' => array('max_length' => 64),
    );
    field_create_field($field);

    // Create the instance.
    $instance = array( 'field_name' => $field_name,
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'bundle' => 'article',
      'label' => 'Alias',
      'description' => 'The article alias.',
      'required' => TRUE,
    );
    field_create_instance($instance);

    watchdog('my_module', t('!field_name was added successfully.', array('!field_name' => $field_name)));
  }
  else {
    watchdog('my_module', t('!field_name already exists.', array('!field_name' => $field_name)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make small changes in your code .In Fields

```
$t = get_t();
$field = array(
   'field_name' => 'map_description',
    'label' => $t('My Description'),
    'type' => 'text',
```

);
field_create_field($field);

```
& Write this in Instance

$t = get_t();
return array(
  'map_description' => array(
    'field_name' => 'map_description',
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => $t('Map Description'),
    'bundle' => 'your_custom_content_type',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'text_textfield'
    ),
    'display' => array(
      'example_node_list' => array(
        'label' => $t('Map Description'),
        'type' => 'text'
      )
    )
  ),
```