# Create a new content type with a custom field ( author )

Tags: nodes, entities

I want to create a new content type " News " with a custom field Author which refers to the author-of-the-content(taxonomy reference or user reference).

This is my .module file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_node_info()
 * Drupal calls this hook when it’s discovering which node types are available. You’ll
 * provide some metadata about your custom node.
 */
function news_node_info() {
    return array(
        'news' => array(
            'name' => t('News'),
            'base' => 'news',
            'description' => t('You can add  News here'),
            'has_title' => TRUE,
            'title_label' => t('News title')
         )
    );
}

/**
 * Implement hook_form()
 */
function news_form($node, $form_state) {
  $form['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('news Title'),
    '#default_value' => !empty($node->title) ? $node->title : '',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#weight' => -5
  );
  return $form;
  }
```

This is my .install file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function news_install() {
    node_types_rebuild();
    $types = node_type_get_types();|
      node_add_body_field($types['news']);
    add_custom_fields();
}

function _news_installed_fields() {
  $t = get_t();
  return array(
    'news_title' => array(
      'field_name' => 'news_title',
      'label' => $t('Title'),
      'type' => 'text',
      ),
    'news_image' => array(
      'field_name' => 'news_image',
      'label' => $t('Image'),
      'type' => 'image',
    ),
    'news_tags' => array(
      'field_name' => 'news_tags',
      'label' => $t('Add Tags'),
      'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference',
      'settings' => array(
        'allowed_values' => array(
          array(
            'vocabulary' => 'news_tags_vocab',
            'parent' => 0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

function _news_installed_instances() {
  $t = get_t();
  return array(
    'news_title' => array(
      'field_name' => 'news_title',
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => $t('The heading of the news topic'),
      'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'text_textfield',
      ),
      'display' => array(
        'news_display_option' => array(
          'label' => $t('The heading of the news topic (display option)'),
          'type' => 'text',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'news_image' => array(
        'field_name' => 'news_image',
        'type' => 'image',
        'label' => $t('Add Image'),
      ),
      'news_tags' => array(
        'field_name' => 'news_tags',
        'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference',
        'label' => $t('Add Tags'),
        'widget' => array(
          'type' => 'taxonomy_autocomplete'
        ),
        'display' => array(
          'default' => array('type' => 'hidden'),
          'teaser' => array('type' => 'hidden')
        ),
      ),
    )
  );
}
function add_custom_fields() {
    foreach (_news_installed_fields() as $field) {
        field_create_field($field);
    }
    foreach (_news_installed_instances() as $fieldinstance) {
        $fieldinstance['entity_type'] = 'node';
        $fieldinstance['bundle'] = 'news';
        print_r($fieldinstance);
        field_create_instance($fieldinstance);
    }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function news_uninstall() {
  // Delete the taxonomy with its terms
  $vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('news_tags_vocab');
  taxonomy_vocabulary_delete($vocab->vid);

  // Gather all the example content that might have been created while this
  // module was enabled.
  $sql = 'SELECT nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = :type';
  $result = db_query($sql, array(':type' => 'news'));
  $nids = array();
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $nids[] = $row->nid;
  }

  // Delete all the nodes at once
  node_delete_multiple($nids);
  // Loop over each of the fields defined by this module and delete
  // all instances of the field, their data, and the field itself.
  foreach (array_keys(_news_installed_fields()) as $field) {
    field_delete_field($field);
  }
  // Loop over any remaining field instances attached to the news
  // content type (such as the body field) and delete them individually.
  $instances = field_info_instances('node', 'news');
  foreach ($instances as $instance_name => $instance) {
    field_delete_instance($instance);
  }
  // Delete our content type
  node_type_delete('news');
  // Purge all field infromation
  field_purge_batch(1000);
}
```

Comment: Request you to explain some more.
Is above code working fine or is there any error.
if any errors let us know so that we can help you out.

Comment: It's working, I want to add another custom field like the image field and the tags field,a custom field instance that contains the author of the content.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should get you started. Got this [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8284/programmatically-create-fields-in-drupal-7). I suggest you check there first in the future.

```
$myField_name = "my_new_field_name";
if(!field_info_field($myField_name)) // check if the field already exists.
{
    $field = array(
        'field_name'    => $myField_name,
        'type'          => 'image',
    );
    field_create_field($field);

    $field_instance = array(
        'field_name'    => $myField_name,
        'entity_type'   => 'node',
        'bundle'        => 'CONTENT_TYPE_NAME',
        'label'         => t('Select an image'),
        'description'   => t(''),
        'widget'        => array(
            'type'      => 'image_image',
            'weight'    => 10,
        ),
        'formatter'     => array(
            'label'     => t('label'),
            'format'    => 'image'
        ),
        'settings'      => array(
            'file_directory'        => 'photos', // save inside "public://photos"
            'max_filesize'          => '4M',
            'preview_image_style'   => 'thumbnail',
            'title_field'           => TRUE,
            'alt_field'             => FALSE,
        )
    );
    field_create_instance($field_instance);
    drupal_set_message("Field created successfully!");
}
```

You can execute this code countless ways. I am not privy to the requirements of your project so its hard for me to make a recommendation. You could hook this into the update/install functions, or you could build it into a page hook in a module, or you could just bootstrap any new php file in the root directory with this:

> require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
>   drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

And you can also refer [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77848/how-do-programmatically-create-fields-for-content-types-and-add-then-to-the-the).

Comment: in this part :
 $field = array(
        'field_name'    => $myField_name,
        'type'          => 'image',
    )
i want to know if there is a type called author that i can use instead of   'type'          => 'image'.

Comment: I don't think so there is a field type called author. Refer [this](https://groups.drupal.org/node/124289)