# Create Text Field Programmatically to Media Type

Tags: 8

I want to create a text field to videos with code. I have the following in the .install file in a custom module:

```
function video_update_8101() {
  $field_name = 'field_video_alternative_text';
  // Make sure the field doesn't already exist.
  if (!FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('file', $field_name)) {
    // Create the field.
    $field = FieldStorageConfig::create(array(
      'field_name' => $field_name,
      'type' => 'text',
      'settings' => array('max_length' => 64),
    ));
    $field->save();

    // Create the instance.
    $instance = FieldStorageConfig::create(array(
      'field_name' => $field_name,
      'entity_type' => 'file',
      'bundle' => 'video',
      'label' => 'Alternative tekst',
      'description' => 'En beskrivelse kommer her.',
      'required' => TRUE,
    ));
    $instance->save();
  }
}
```

I get the following when running update.php

```
Attempt to create a field storage field_video_alternative_text with no entity_type.                                                                                                                                                                                 [error]
Performing emu_video_update_8101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [ok]
Failed: Attempt to create a field storage field_video_alternative_text with no entity_type.
```

Furthermore, I want this to happen when I install the module. I suppose it's not at this point?

Edit: I got inspiration from this post: [How do programmatically create fields for content types, and ADD them to the the content type form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77848/how-do-programmatically-create-fields-for-content-types-and-add-them-to-the-the)

Comment: To the last point: `hook_update_N` is for updates only, they won't be executed upon install. The point of them is to allow older versions of the module to get up to date with the current version that they're upgrading to. The initial state of the latest version of the module should reflect the state the older version of the module would be in _after_ the update. Think `hook_install` or config/install/*.yml

Comment: So simply changing the function name to video_install will do that part? And in that case, will that then be the _right_ way to do it rather than config/install?

Comment: Yeah exactly. You might want to think about removing it again in `hook_uninstall`, or at least checking whether it exists first before creating in `hook_install`. Just in case you need to reinstall the module

Comment: Ah, you edited that comment after I replied...the "yeah exactly" was to the first part. My own opinion is that adding config/install/field.storage.node.field_name.yml and the complementary field.field one is the right way to approach it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7 fields were shared across all content types; in Drupal 8 they're shared across a single entity type.

As such you've just missed the `entity_type` when creating the storage:

```
$field = FieldStorageConfig::create(array(
  'entity_type' => 'file',
  'field_name' => $field_name,
  'type' => 'text',
  'settings' => array('max_length' => 64),
));
```

As an aside, `hook_update_N` is for updates only, those functions won't be executed upon install. The point of them is to allow older versions of the module to get up to date with the current version that they're upgrading to. The initial state of the latest version of the module should reflect the state the older version of the module would be in after the update.

You can use `hook_install` or config files in config/install/*.yml to perform initial setup of your module upon install.